# Returning value of a promise in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise

I'm trying a very basic thing - find a user in database and return one of the fields for a specific found record. I want to use promises, in part for educational purpose.

```
var username = "user1" // assuming this exists: User({username: "user1", city: "London"})

function getUser(username) {
    var promise = User.findOne({username: username}).exec();

    var output = promise.then( function(user) {
        return user.city;
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }); 
    return output;
}
```

With the code given above, assuming there is a user with given data, the output variable is still a promise. How can I get the actual value of it? I have a hunch that my problem is with return statement not being async, i.e. I return output before it actually was resolved. What would be the correct way to return the value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You return the promise, to get the value when the promise is resolved you should call `then` on the returned promise:

```
function getUser(username) {
    return User
        .findOne({username: username})
        .then(function(user) {
            return user.city;
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
}

// How to use getUser
getUser('John')
    .then(function(city) {
        console.log(city);
    });
```